# Example for SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement `ExpandableListView` in android. But I did not find any good tutorial.

I have to draw a check box and a textview on my parent view. On child view the first item contains a checkbox an image view and the last three are text views. Can any one please help me how to extend `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`?

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us your effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place to look for an example on customizing the adapter of an `ExpandableListView` is the samples application provided with the SDK that you can find at:

> {sdk_root}/samples/platform-xx/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableListView1.java

For the question's case(the same layout for all groups followed by two types of layouts for the children rows)below you can find an example of a custom adapter. Notice that I extended `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, I've done this because extending `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` makes sense only for small changes(as its name suggest is designed to tackle basic usage scenarios).

```
private static class CustomExpandableAdapter extends
        BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    // identifiers for our two types of rows, if the child rows are the same
    // this aren't required.
    private static final int FIRST_CHILD = 0;
    private static final int OTHER_CHILD = 1;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> mGroupData;
    private List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> mChildData;

    public CustomExpandableAdapter(Context context,
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> makeGroupData,
            List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> makeChildData) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mGroupData = makeGroupData;
        mChildData = makeChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        if (childPosition == 0) {
            return FIRST_CHILD; // this is the first child row so return
                                // FIRST_CHILD as the type of row
        }
        return OTHER_CHILD;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildTypeCount() {
        return 2; // two types of children rows
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getChild(int groupPosition,
            int childPosition) {
        return mChildData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // if we don't have a recycled row available inflate one BASED on
        // the type of row this child should have.
        int type = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ChildViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ChildViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case FIRST_CHILD:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.view_expandlistchild, parent, false); // contains only an ImageView and a CheckBox
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageViewChild);
                holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChild);
                break;
            case OTHER_CHILD:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false); // contains only a TextView
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final HashMap<String, Object> item = getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);
        // we set the data on the row based on the type of the row(so we
        // access only the views we do have in the layout)
        switch (type) {
        case FIRST_CHILD:
            holder.image.setImageResource((Integer) item.get(CHILD_IMAGE));
            // pass in the checked listener this as a tag so we can identify
            // the proper data position and update it
            holder.check.setTag(new PositionsWrapper(groupPosition,
                    childPosition));
            holder.check
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(
                                CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // set the new status of the checked item
                            // otherwise the status will be erased as the
                            // user scrolls down and up
                            PositionsWrapper pw = (PositionsWrapper) buttonView
                                    .getTag();
                            mChildData.get(pw.groupPosition)
                                    .get(pw.childPosition)
                                    .put(CHILD_STATUS, isChecked);
                        }
                    });
            holder.check.setChecked((Boolean) item.get(CHILD_STATUS));
            break;
        case OTHER_CHILD:
            holder.text.setText((CharSequence) item.get(CHILD_TEXT));
            break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mChildData.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroupData.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroupData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // normal row building like in any custom adapter
        GroupViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new GroupViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_expandlistgroup,
                    parent, false); // contains a TextView and a CheckBox
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
            holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxGroup);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final HashMap<String, Object> item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        holder.text.setText((CharSequence) item.get(GROUP_TEXT));
        holder.check.setTag(Integer.valueOf(groupPosition));
        holder.check
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // again, save the new status in the data list so we
                        // keep the status as the user scrolls
                        Integer groupPosition = (Integer) buttonView
                                .getTag();
                        mGroupData.get(groupPosition).put(GROUP_STATUS,
                                isChecked);
                    }
                });
        holder.check.setChecked((Boolean) item.get(GROUP_STATUS));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Simple class that wraps two integers representing the group and child
     * row position.
     * 
     * @author Luksprog
     * 
     */
    private static class PositionsWrapper {

        int groupPosition;
        int childPosition;

        PositionsWrapper(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            this.groupPosition = groupPosition;
            this.childPosition = childPosition;
        }

    }

    // basic ViewHolder classes
    private static class GroupViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox check;
    }

    private static class ChildViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        CheckBox check;
        TextView text;
    }

}
```

The full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/view/ExpandableListViewExample.java).

Comment: @Howard tried some sample project but when i changed them they showed force close but now understand the concept how to draw ExpandableListView.@slukian thanks for the link.

Comment: This answer is pretty useless. You should provide an example